# How to design the ui similar to list view in salesforce lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist, slds

I am trying to design a picklist which will looks similar to List view in lightning. Is it possible to achieve this using SLDS? 
if not any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SLDS data table:

[Data Tables
Component Overview](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/)

Comment: How to implement list view using data Tables. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria today you have standard lightning components for that (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm). try it and if you have questions - add your own question at this site.

Comment: Yes. I have a vf tab. In that I have to show list view and filter options. I can achieve list view but how to create and edit a list view from vf page?

Comment: I don't know about vf page - my answer is all about lightning component